# Select from two tables and sum

Tags: sql

i have a little question in my syntax please help me.

```
Table TransM
Code_Project   Code_Name  Code_Stat   Project_Name
17-0004        A          1           ABC  
17-0004        A          2           ABC   
17-0004        B          1           DEF 

Tabel TransW
Code_Project     Code_Name      Total
17-0004          A              1000
17-0004          A              1500
17-0004          A              1200
17-0004          B              1600
```

The Result i want is like this :

```
Code_Project   Code_Name   Project_Name   GrandTotal
17-0004        A           ABC            3700
17-0004        B           DEF            1600
```

i use this syntax and the grandtotal is wrong

```
SELECT
  a.Code_Project,
  a.Code_Name,
  a.Project_Name,
  SUM(b.Total) AS GrandTotal
FROM
  TransM a
  INNER JOIN TransW b
    ON a.Code_Project = b.Code_Project
    AND a.Code_Name = b.Code_Name
WHERE a.Code_Project = '17-0004'
GROUP BY a.Code_Project,
  a.Code_Name,
  a.Project_Name
```

Please tell me the right syntax, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple rows in `TransM` matching multiple rows in `TransW` because the `Code_Project, Code_Name, Project_Name` are not unique in `TransM`.

You could get the `distinct` set as a subquery/derived table and join using that like so:

```
select 
    a.Code_Project
  , a.Code_Name
  , a.Project_Name
  , sum(b.Total) as GrandTotal
from (select distinct Code_Project, Code_Name, Project_Name from TransM) a
  inner join TransW b
    on a.Code_Project = b.Code_Project
   and a.Code_Name = b.Code_Name
where a.Code_Project = '17-0004'
group by 
    a.Code_Project
  , a.Code_Name
  , a.Project_Name
```

If there are multiple distinct values for `Project_Name` for a given `Code_Project, Code_Name` then you will still get duplicates. In that case you would need to determine how to choose which `Project_Name` to return, or use `min()` or `max()` just to pick one like so:

```
select 
    a.Code_Project
  , a.Code_Name
  , a.Project_Name
  , sum(b.Total) as GrandTotal
from (
    select m.Code_Project, m.Code_Name, max(m.Project_Name) as Project_Name
    from TransM m
    group by m.Code_Project, m.Code_Name
    ) a
  inner join TransW b
    on a.Code_Project = b.Code_Project
   and a.Code_Name = b.Code_Name
where a.Code_Project = '17-0004'
group by 
    a.Code_Project
  , a.Code_Name
  , a.Project_Name
```

---

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/RRGFQM14769

returns:

```
+--------------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| Code_Project | Code_Name | Project_Name | GrandTotal |
+--------------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| 17-0004      | A         | ABC          |       3700 |
| 17-0004      | B         | DEF          |       1600 |
+--------------+-----------+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, yeah i get more multiple distinct values and i understand for your answer

Comment: @William I'm not sure what double sum you mean, but based on the example data provided it looks right in the demos: http://rextester.com/RRGFQM14769

Comment: sorry sir, i wrong to see the grandtotal. once again sorry and thank's

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with `union all` and `group by`:

```
select Code_Project, Code_Name,
       max(Project_Name) as Project_Name, 
       sum(Total) as GrandTotal
from ((select Code_Project, Code_Name, Project_Name, 0 as Total
       from TransM
      ) union all
      (select Code_Project, Code_Name, NULL Project_Name, Total
       from TransW
      ) 
     ) mw
group by Code_Project, Code_Name;
```